# Display image on a Java button

Tags: java, button

```
xstButton.setIcon(new ImageIcon("D://icon-tender-check-press.png"));
```

I am using this line of code to display an image on a Java button.

I cannot see the desired image on the button, need help!!!

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Does `new ImageIcon("D://icon-tender-check-press.png")` return the correct object?

Comment: yes it return the correct object, i can see the image's correct height and width.

Comment: Did you consider using a `MediaTracker` to monitor the loaded state of the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try it like this:

```
Image image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("D://icon-tender-check-press.png"));
button.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
```

But i would suggest to create a Folder in your project to store images:

```
Image image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("images/icon-tender-check-press.png"));
    button.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
```

Although i am not exactly sure what your question is

Answer (score 0):

Probably file "D://icon-tender-check-press.png" doesn't exists or is not a valid image.
Check it exists first.

```
File f = new File("D://icon-tender-check-press.png");
if(f.exists() && !f.isDirectory()) { 
    System.out.println("File exists");
}
```